# Отключение ошибок Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

В bootstrap.php указанно:

```
Kohana::init(array(
  'base_url'   => '/',
        'index_file' => FALSE,
        'errors'=>FALSE,
        'profiling'=>FALSE,
));
```

Но это никак не повлияло на вывод ошибок. Все равно обработчик встрявает.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `bootstrap.php`

```
Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;
```

или в `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV production
```